# JS function that scrolls an element into view taking into account possible scrollable and positioned parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I was looking for a function that would scroll a given element into view with some smart behavior:

- if an element is descendant of a scrollable element - that ancestor is scrolled rather than body.
- if an element is descendant  of a positioned element - body won't be scrolled.

I didn't find any suitable function, so I made one and wanted some expert opinion on it. Please check the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DNGWLh5cH1Cr1coZbwpa?p=preview . There are problems with animated scroll in FF, so please use Chrome to check the logic.

To illustrate, what I'm looking for - here is the first update that came to mind - if we reached an element that can scroll, lets call it SC (Scroll Parent), we should not only scroll SC to make the target visible inside it, but also recursively scroll SC itself into view, since it may outside of the currently visible are of the page. Here is the update plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DNGWLh5cH1Cr1coZbwpa?p=preview (also applied fix for FF scrolling problem).

And here is the code of the function

```
  function scrollTo(target){
  //Position delta is used for scrollable elements other than BODY
  var combinedPositionDelta = 0;  
  var previousParent = $(target);
  var parent = $(target).parent();

  while(parent){

    combinedPositionDelta += previousParent.position().top - parent.position().top;

    //If we reached body
    if(parent.prop("tagName").toUpperCase() == "BODY"){
      scrollBody(target.offset().top);
      break;
    }

    //if we reached an element that can scroll
    if(parent[0].scrollHeight > parent.outerHeight()){
      scrollElementByDelta(parent,combinedPositionDelta);
      //Recursively scroll parent into view, since it itself might not be visible
      scrollTo(parent);
      break;
    }

    //if we reached a apositioned element - break
    if(parent.css('position').toUpperCase() != 'STATIC'){
      console.log("Stopping due to positioned parent " + parent[0].outerHTML);
      break;
    }

    previousParent = parent;
    parent = parent.parent();

  }

}

var offsetSkin = 20;
function scrollElementByDelta(element,offsetDelta){
   $(element).animate({
        scrollTop: element.scrollTop() + (offsetDelta - offsetSkin) 
    }, 1000);
}

function scrollBody(offset){
     $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: offset - offsetSkin
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is here? Do you want a code review? Or is there a specific issue you're asking about?

Comment: I want to end up with a universal function for this case, so I would call it a peer review.

Comment: @IvanKoshelew What does "if an element is descendant of a positioned element" mean? All elements are positioned... And, unless you have an error with the code, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this question

Comment: "A positioned element is an element whose computed position property is relative, absolute, fixed or sticky." ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position I haven't seen before http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , but I don't thinks the question really belongs there. Lets say the question is "I need a truly universal JS function that would scroll a given arbitrary HTML element into view". My code is just a demo - the right solution might be totally different, so long as it does the job.

Comment: @ZachSaucier, the above comment is meant for you.

Comment: @ZachSaucier i am not sure if i understand `Code Review` right, but for me it is working code, where some other devs can look at it and say "very good" or "this part of the code can be improved"

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but it seems to behave the same as element.scrollIntoView()...

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Code Review Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/considering-a-migration-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review)

Answer (score 4):

Well I'm Using this one which works very well for me:

```
function scrollIntoView (element, alignTop) {
    var document = element.ownerDocument;
    var origin = element, originRect = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
    var hasScroll = false;
    var documentScroll = this.getDocumentScrollElement(document);

    while (element) {

        if (element == document.body) {
            element = documentScroll;
        } else {
            element = element.parentNode;
        }

        if (element) {
            var hasScrollbar = (!element.clientHeight) ? false : element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;


            if (!hasScrollbar) {
                if (element == documentScroll) {
                    element = null;
                }
                continue;
            }

            var rects;
            if (element == documentScroll) {
                rects = {
                    left : 0,
                    top : 0
                };
            } else {
                rects = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            }

            // check that elementRect is in rects
            var deltaLeft = originRect.left - (rects.left + (parseInt(element.style.borderLeftWidth, 10) | 0));
            var deltaRight = originRect.right
                            - (rects.left + element.clientWidth + (parseInt(element.style.borderLeftWidth, 10) | 0));
            var deltaTop = originRect.top - (rects.top + (parseInt(element.style.borderTopWidth, 10) | 0));
            var deltaBottom = originRect.bottom
                            - (rects.top + element.clientHeight + (parseInt(element.style.borderTopWidth, 10) | 0));

            // adjust display depending on deltas
            if (deltaLeft < 0) {
                element.scrollLeft += deltaLeft;
            } else if (deltaRight > 0) {
                element.scrollLeft += deltaRight;
            }

            if (alignTop === true && !hasScroll) {
                element.scrollTop += deltaTop;
            } else if (alignTop === false && !hasScroll) {
                element.scrollTop += deltaBottom;
            } else {
                if (deltaTop < 0) {
                    element.scrollTop += deltaTop;
                } else if (deltaBottom > 0) {
                    element.scrollTop += deltaBottom;
                }
            }

            if (element == documentScroll) {
                element = null;
            } else {
                // readjust element position after scrolls, and check if vertical scroll has changed.
                // this is required to perform only one alignment
                var nextRect = origin.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (nextRect.top != originRect.top) {
                    hasScroll = true;
                }
                originRect = nextRect;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The **only** working solution in the internet which works consistently with absolutely positioned divs, overflows etc etc. Trust me! I checked many solutions.
The only part which is unclear is `this.getDocumentScrollElement(document);` in the code. It can be replaced with `document.scrollingElement` with [this polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/document.scrollingElement).

Comment: What is `this.getDocumentScrollElement`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind venturing into jQuery, the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin is the best bet. It handles most needs and gives a very refined smooth trasition.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, from the https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo i got  "•The plugin might fail to scroll an element, to an inner node that is nested in more scrollable elements. This seems like an odd situation anyway.", which is one of the reasons I went looking in the first place.